# i am not able to find directory with cd (cd ~/scripts)

Tags: python, linux, debugging, activeadmin

Coursera course:- [Troubleshooting and Debugging Techniques](https://www.coursera.org/learn/troubleshooting-debugging-techniques?)

Hi, I am shashank I'm trying to complete Qwiklabs Assessment: [Debugging Python Scripts](https://googlecoursera.qwiklabs.com/focuses/47750) which is first weak. but in that i have to go in cd ~/scripts error;- (-bash: cd: /home/student-04-4d7a5d258a7a/scripts: No such file or directory
) directory but in my quick lab VM this directory is not present what should I do and even I try 2nd-week assignment in that I have to put a command ls ~/scripts it shows me an error:- ls: cannot access '/home/student-04-0e32c999a759/scripts': No such file or directory.

Comment: Does `cd ~` or `ls -ltra ~` work? Most likely your home directory `~` doesn't have a `scripts` folder.

Comment: As kydreth pointed out there is no such directory in your home directory(~ means home). Maybe you need to create one!